# Store additional data in task comments

Tags: phabricator

I'm looking for a way to log some structured data nearby task comments.

It would be preferable to handle it like other actions from *Add Action* actions menu. Here is how I see it [interface mock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1rQA.png)

Have you got any idea how to do it? If it is of course possible that way, otherwise how to achieve similar effect?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the data, as an action would be a little bit hard. You need to have the whole thing as an extension as it is declared in [Phabricator documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/). But simple value field can be added as JSON configuration values in Phabricator without changing anything.[Configuring Custom Fields](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/) will help.